# Remove SOAP Envelope namespace from XML

Tags: xml, rest, soap

I am using `curl` to write the following in a windows command prompt:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "<test/>" -X PUT "http://localhost:9092/restapi"
```

My application has the following code:

```
public class RestAPI implements Provider<Source>
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Endpoint.publish(url, new RestAPI());
    }


    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;


    @Override
    public Source invoke(Source request)
    {
        if (wsContext == null)
           throw new RuntimeException("dependency injection failed on wsContext");
        MessageContext msgContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        switch (((String) msgContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD)).toUpperCase().trim())
        {
            case "PUT":
                return processPut(msgContext, request);
        'etc.
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Source processPut(MessageContext msgContext, Source request)
    {
        // get the XML as a String
        Transformer transformer;
        try
        {
            transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(request, new StreamResult(stringWriter));

            System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
        }
        catch (TransformerException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

The output I see from the `System.out.println` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

At what point was the SOAP namespace added, and how can I remove it? (I'm creating a REST API, not a SOAP one)

Comment: Where are you creating the source? The issue might be there & not in transformer

Comment: I'm using `Endpoint.publish` and my api class implements `Provider<Source>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `JAX-WS` for the implementation of services - it is for building `XML SOAP` services. So SOAP namespaces will be added automatically. If you plan to build REST services use JAX-RS implementation libraries like **Jersey**

Comment: I was following the tutorial at https://www.javaworld.com/article/3222065/web-services-in-java-se-part-3-creating-restful-web-services.html

Comment: Well, SOAP web services are also on top of HTTP, so we can use the framework to behave like REST if you like. But it might have impacts like what you had. Probably there are ways to avoid namespacing but if you consider to build REST services - use JAX-RS and not JAX-WS.

Comment: OK Thanks. Area there any built-in JAX-RS providers, or would I have to have a 3rd-party JAR like Jersey?

Comment: JAX-RS is a specification and Jersey is the reference implementation. There are other implementations like Restlet, RestEasy or you can use spring boot etc. All these frameworks are quite easy to understand and ready to use stuff.

Comment: I am trying to just run it in a jar file in Eclipse, rather than using a server (at least just for learning purposes). All the tutorials I see for REST use Tomcat/etc. Is that because it can't be done, or just isn't the done thing?

Comment: Well you need a server to expose services as a standard practice. You can embed it in eclipse and run. I don't see a big hurdle there :-)